# Unsupported CUDA version 5.0 detected, you need CUDA 6.5

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I've been happily using CUDA with cycles for a while now - set `Cycles Renderer` up top, then `File->User Preferences->System->Compute Device=CUDA` and in `Preferences`(bottom right panel)`-> Render tab->Render section->Device=GPU Compute`. Can then `shift-z` to use cycles to render the preview in addition to just rendering.

But firing it up today results in:

```
Unsupported CUDA version 5.0 detected, you need CUDA 6.5.
```

Which is strange, because:

```
> ls -la /usr/local/
cuda-5.0
cuda-6.0
cuda-6.5
cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-6.5

> export | grep -i cuda
declare -x CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda"
declare -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin:..."

> nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jul_17_21:41:27_CDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12
```

As far as I can see my environment is already set for 6.5. I get the same for both the Fedora 21 package (2.72) and one I compiled from the source (2.73). How is blender finding the older version? I suspect I've done something to mess up my environment but can't find what it is. Any ideas?

---

Update:

`strace` shows blender goes straight to the `cuda-5.0` directory, perhaps due to this:

```
> grep "/usr/local/cuda-5.0/" /usr/bin/blender
Binary file /usr/bin/blender matches
```

Reinstalling cuda-6.5 didn't fix it, but it did break my permissions, so:

```
sudo chmod -R o+rX /usr/local/cuda-6.5/
```

I have recently updated to nvidia driver 346.35, maybe that did something to my environment. Either way it seems like blender first looks in 
`/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/` for `nvcc` and then `/usr/local/cuda/bin/` (this seems like a bug to me). If it finds cuda 6.5 first, either via simlinking `cuda-5.0` to `cuda-6.5` or moving/renaming the directory, I get hit with this error:

```
Compiling CUDA kernel ...
"/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc" -arch=sm_52 ...
nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm_52' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'
```

Similar blender error mentioned [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?344678-nvcc-fatal-Value-sm_50-is-not-defined-for-option-gpu-architecture) and [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?259605-nvcc-fatal-Value-sm_30-is-not-defined-for-option-gpu-architecture), and theano error [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/Qjq4I_Q6SHA). I have just moved from a gtx titan to a 980. Maybe that's related.

**UPDATE:** Yes, it's the new card. Going back to the titan works just fine. Surprised others don't have similar issues with the 980.

Answer (score 1):

As your `/usr/local/` directory shows you have installed multiple versions of CUDA (`/usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall` would only uninstall the last one). When upgrading I had first to uninstall all CUDA files:

From [pre-installation-actions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions)

Use the following command to uninstall a Toolkit runfile installation:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/cuda-X.Y/bin/uninstall_cuda_X.Y.pl
```

Use the following command to uninstall a Driver runfile installation:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall
```

Use the following commands to uninstall a RPM/Deb installation:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove <package_name>          # Ubuntu
$ sudo yum remove <package_name>                      # Fedora/Redhat/CentOS
$ sudo zypper remove <package_name>                   # OpenSUSE/SLES
```

Check for remaining packages:

```
$ dpkg -l
```

and remove them also. After a re-install of the most recent version should work.

Comment: My problem isn't uninstalling cuda, I just want to point blender to the right one. That's what it looks like the automatically created symlink is there for. I can compile and run my own cuda stuff just fine. I just want to know what mechanism blender is using to find cuda.

Comment: Then you could launch Blender with `strace` and grep for cuda paths.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it's time for me to give up for the day.

Comment: At a guess I think blender is detecting a newer architecture than the current `nvcc` supports. Is there a way I can tell cycles to use an older `-arch` version?

Comment: @jozxyqk I don't know, sorry.