# linux+cycles+cuda: nvcc fatal: Value 'sm_52' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, linux

I'm getting the error in the title. This has some of the same problems from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24244/1713). Apparently this is an issue with an earlier version of the CUDA 6.5 toolkit, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943010/nvcc-arch-sm-52-gives-error-value-sm-52-is-not-defined-for-option-gpu-archi).

However, even after installing the CUDA 7.0 toolkit, I'm still getting the following error:

```
"/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin/nvcc" -arch=sm_52 -m64 --cubin "/usr/share/blender/2.74/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel/kernel.cu" -o "/home/jozxyqk/.config/blender/2.74/cache/cycles_kernel_sm52_680206C327F9D352594B0E249634D211.cubin" --ptxas-options="-v" --use_fast_math -I"/usr/share/blender/2.74/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel" -DNVCC -D__KERNEL_CUDA_VERSION__=60
nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm_52' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'
CUDA kernel compilation failed, see console for details.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Can you give some more information about the problem and your situation?

Comment: @GilElbaz not really sure what you're after. Is was a Linux permissions issue for me (after installing the cuda toolkit). Did the answer not work? If your issue is a bit different maybe start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons:

1. The cuda-7.0 toolkit installer failed to properly set permissions, so blender can't see the `nvcc` from the proper location.
2. When blender can't read using the symlink `cuda` in `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc` it seems to search for `nvcc` using `cuda-<version>/` instead. But it does it in the *wrong* order, also without reporting the permission issue.

Without others-readable permissions on `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/`, the symlink `/usr/local/cuda` fails and blender tries `/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin/nvcc` even though a newer `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc` exists.

The **solution**:

```
sudo chmod -R o+rX /usr/local/cuda-7.0/
```

Had no other toolkits been installed the error would have been:

```
which: no nvcc in ($PATH)
CUDA nvcc compiler not found. Install CUDA toolkit in default location.
```